# Python Pulp replicating Excel's solver

Tags: python, pulp

When i try to use the math.log function in the objective expression, this error pops out. Can someone help me understand how can a add the formula that i need to optimize?

model_MPL += samples * (math.log(beta_var) - beta_var * math.log(alfa_var)) + suma

I am trying to reproduce Excel's solver in order to optimize the alpha and beta parameters of a weibull distribution.

```
data = np.array([509,660,386,753,811,613,848,725,315,872,487,512])

def func_aplicada(x):
    return (beta_last -1)*math.log(x)-(x/alfa)**beta_last

alfa = 688.916073521629
beta_last = 3.979166666666667

suma=0
samples=data.shape[0]
for i in range(0,samples):
    suma += func_aplicada(data[i])

print('Cantidad de muestras = ',samples, '/ sumaacum =',suma)

import pulp as pl

model_MPL = pl.LpProblem("MPL", pl.LpMaximize)

beta_var = pl.LpVariable("beta_var",beta_last*0.5 , beta_last*1.5)
alfa_var = pl.LpVariable("alfa_var", alfa*0.5, alfa*1.5)

model_MPL += alfa_var>=0.1
model_MPL += beta_var>=0.1

model_MPL += samples * (math.log(beta_var) - beta_var * math.log(alfa_var)) + suma 


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-08c6614fb718> in <module>
     22 model_MPL += beta_var>=0.1
     23 
---> 24 model_MPL += samples * (math.log(beta_var) - beta_var * math.log(alfa_var)) + suma

TypeError: must be real number, not LpVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates `alpha_var` and `beta_var` are of the type `LpVariable` but you want there numerical value.

Call `alpha_var.value()` to get the value of a LpVariable.

```
model_MPL += samples * (math.log(beta_var.value()) - beta_var.value() * math.log(alfa_var.value())) + suma
```

Comment: I change that and a have a new error type                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
---> 29 model_MPL += samples * (math.log(beta_var.value()) - beta_var.value() * math.log(alfa_var.value())) + suma

TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use lpSum in the objective function

```
import pulp as pl

model_MPL = pl.LpProblem("MPL", pl.LpMaximize)

beta_var = pl.LpVariable("beta_var",beta_last*0.5 , beta_last*1.5)
alfa_var = pl.LpVariable("alfa_var", alfa*0.5, alfa*1.5)

model_MPL += alfa_var>=0.1
model_MPL += beta_var>=0.1

model_MPL += lpSum([sample * (math.log(beta_var) - sample * beta_var + sample * math.log(alfa_var)) 
                    for sample in samples]) + suma
```